# How to reorganize matrix according to location requirements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to specify a location replacement for matrix reorganization. For example,  when I specify the location replacement rule to be `{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {2, 3, 0, 0}` (where `0` means the matrix element is replaced with `0`), a 4-by-4 matrix `Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]` is recombined as follows:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[1, 1], a[1, 2], 0}, {0, a[2, 1], a[2, 2], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

When I specify the location replacement rule to be `{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {3, 4, 0, 0}` , a 4-by-4 matrix `Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]` is recombined as follows:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {0, 0, a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}}
```

How can I write this custom function to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your notation for describing the replacements most confusing. But one can do something like this:

```
A = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
ilist = {1, 2};
jlist = {2, 3};
B = SparseArray[
   Tuples[{ilist, jlist}] -> Flatten[A[[ilist, jlist]]],
   Dimensions[A]
   ];
Normal@B
```

> {{0, a[1, 2], a[1, 3], 0}, {0, a[2, 2], a[2, 3], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

Here, `ilist` is the lists of rows that you want to preserve and `jlist` is the corresponding list of columns.

This is also possible:

```
B = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[A]];
B[[ilist, jlist]] = A[[ilist, jlist]]
```

This, too; but it is rather slow:

```
ReplacePart[
 ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[A]],
 Thread[Tuples[{ilist, jlist}] -> Flatten[A[[ilist, jlist]]]]
 ]
```

Comment: I don't know if you have heard of the matrix displacement method in structural mechanics. I want to realize the assembly function of the stiffness matrix. I will modify this problem in detail tomorrow.

Comment: No, I do not know it and I obviously do not need to know it in order to produce the matrices that you are looking for. I observed that you have recently posted many posts that involve a lot of lingo from structural mechanics. In most of the cases, knowing this slang was actually not necessary to phrase or answer(!) your underlying question. _This is not a forum on structural mechanics._

Comment: So my advice to you for future: Please to not assume that everybody here is knowledgeable in structural mechanics; instead, find the mathematical core of your problem and ask the question in a way that most people here can understand. _Do not try to force everybody to learn structural mechanics._

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will abstract the problem into the minimum demo code containing the problem in the future (minimal working example). I try not to use other professional terms in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think writing code like this can fulfill the requirements:

```
A = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}];
f[x1_, x2_] := {x1[[1]], x2[[1]]} -> {x1[[2]], x2[[2]]}
rule1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> {1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3}
rule2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> {1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0}

s1 = DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[f, Thread[rule1], Thread[rule1]]], 
   HoldPattern[{_, _} -> {a_, b_}] /; a == 0 || b == 0] /. 
  HoldPattern[
    x1_ -> x2_List] :> (x2 -> Part[A, x1 /. List -> Sequence])
s2 = DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[f, Thread[rule2], Thread[rule2]]], 
   HoldPattern[{_, _} -> {a_, b_}] /; a == 0 || b == 0] /. 
  HoldPattern[
    x1_ -> x2_List] :> (x2 -> Part[A, x1 /. List -> Sequence])
B1 = SparseArray[Normal[Merge[s1, Total]], 4];
B2 = SparseArray[Normal[Merge[s2, Total]], 4];
Normal@B1
Normal@B2
```

Maybe this code can be simplified more succinctly and efficiently.